# C++ Boost ASIO: how to read/write with a timeout?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

From reading other Stack Overflow entries and the `boost::asio` documentation, I've confirmed that there is no synchronous ASIO read/write calls that also provide an easy-to-use timeout as a parameter to the call.

I'm in the middle of converting an old-school Linux socket application with select(2) calls that employs timeouts, and I need to do more-or-less the same.

So what is the best way to do this in `boost::asio`? Looking at the asio documentation, there are many confusing examples of various things to do with timers, but I'm quite confused.

I'd love to see a simple-to-read example of this: **Read from a socket, but wait for a maximum of X seconds after which the function either returns with nothing, or returns with whatever it was able to read from the socket before the timeout expired.**

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is confusing about this example:  http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.4.7/src/examples/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp - The essential logic is, you despatch 2 async tasks, one a read/write and the other a time-out if the read/write returns first you kill the deadline timer, if the deadline timer returns the logic is the read/write is still outstanding - from there you proceed with your time-out logic. very very simple.

Comment: There is one corner case that might arise in hf networking that is related to the queuing of the callbacks. the timeout cb is queued, then the read/write is queued. you encounter the timeout cb and begin to execute time-out logic when in reality the read/write had completed, a possible solution i've seen is something similar to double check lock - in short perform a secondary timeout when the first timeout returns, but then this has the same problem what if the read/write is queued after the 2nd timeout is queue...

Comment: Just remember a timeout is a hard condition, you're saying if i don't get something in a certain amount of time, i will do something specific - this includes the fact that the read/write may have alreadyoccured and is on its way to you, that doesn't change the fact that you haven't recieved it as of yet.

Comment: @zenikoder I believe the confusion is that the timeout constructs provided by asio enforce using the asynchronous methods, they cannot be used with synchronous methods.

Comment: @Sam: you can create a synchronous timeout, you just hide an asynch call behind a synchrouch interface that blocks, until either a timeout or a read/write occurs.

Comment: One possible solution for READ, would be to call socket.available() to determine the number of bytes available for reading, and invoke read_some with that exact (or less, never more) amount. The call shall not block and you can enforce a timeout around that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been brought up on the asio mailing lists, there's a [ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2832) requesting the feature as well. To summarize, it is suggested to use asynchronous methods if you desire timeouts and cancellability.

---

If you cannot convert to asynchronous methods, you might try the `SO_RCVTIMEO` and `SO_SNDTIMEO` socket options. They can be set with `setsockopt`, the descriptor can be obtained with the [boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::native](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/native.html) method. The `man 7 socket` man page says

> SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO
>                 Specify the receiving or sending timeouts until reporting an
>   error.  The argument is a struct
>   timeval.  If an input or output
>   function blocks for this period of
>   time, and data has  been  sent
>                 or  received,  the return value of that function will be
>   the amount of data transferred; if no
>   data has been transferred and the
>   timeout has been reached then -1 is
>   returned with errno set to
>                 EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK just as if the socket was specified to
>   be non-blocking.  If the timeout is
>   set to zero (the default) then the
>   operation will never timeout. 
>   Timeouts  only  have  effect
>                 for system calls that perform socket I/O (e.g., read(2),
>   recvmsg(2), send(2), sendmsg(2));
>   timeouts have no effect for select(2),
>   poll(2), epoll_wait(2), etc.

Comment: Did you read CH's response to the request? ASIO replicates OS functionality in C++, if you requrie some kind of time-out functionality, you're more than welcome to implement it using the bit-n-pieces ASIO provides.

Answer (score 7):

I used some [asio docs](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_3_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SettableSocketOption.html) to produce this:

```
class TimeoutAdjust
{
public:
  TimeoutAdjust(unsigned int dwTimeout) : m_dwTimeout(dwTimeout) {};

  template<class Protocol>
  int level(const Protocol& p) const {return SOL_SOCKET;}

  template<class Protocol>
  int name(const Protocol& p) const {return SO_SNDTIMEO;}

  template<class Protocol>
  const void* data(const Protocol& p) const {return &m_dwTimeout;}

  template<class Protocol>
  size_t size(const Protocol& p) const {return sizeof(m_dwTimeout);}
private:
  unsigned int m_dwTimeout;
};
```

Usage:

```
TimeoutAdjust adjust(5000);
sSocket.set_option(adjust);
```

I debugged it, and it appears to do what it is supposed to.

Comment: What I read here is that `SO_SNDTIMEO` takes a `timeval`, rather than an `unsigned int`. http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket

Comment: Ah, the MS docs use a DWORD for SO_SNDTIMEO.  Looks like timeval is a pair of long ints, so reader beware.

MS docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms740532(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: After using above code i am getting an exception                Exception: set_option: Invalid argument.If you have some reference code then please share the same.