# Boost::asio udp socket - how should I use the API to allow cancellation of reads?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, boost-asio

I am using `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket` to communicate. I use `socket.receive_from(...)` to receive messages from clients. This is working fine for now, but I want to be able to shut down my server. Right now I am calling `receive_from` in a while-loop, which depends on a bool condition which I can set. However, this is pretty useless if I cannot force the thread to exit `receive_from` at regular intervals or at a certain call.

Is this even possible? I have tried googling, but found no clear answer. I have tried using `socket.cancel()` but this seems to have no effect.

Am I using the socket in the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no good way to do what you want using the synchronous `receive_from` method. You should use the asynchronous `async_receive_from` method if you desire timeouts and cancelability. There's a [ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2832) on the Boost.Asio trac website describing this.

I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553162/c-boost-asio-how-to-read-write-with-a-timeout/4555577#4555577) recently that you might find useful as well.

Comment: Thanks! Confirmation was all I needed. Was hoping I could avoid the extra complexity.