# Can I read from a socket synchronously using Boost.Asio with a timeout on a multithreaded I/O service?

Tags: sockets, timeout, boost-asio, synchronous

I have an application that uses Boost.Asio for TCP and UDP socket communications. I understand that the 'A' in "Asio" stands for *Asynchronous*, so the library is bent toward encouraging you to use asynchronous I/O when possible. I have a few cases where synchronous socket reads are preferable. At the same time, however, I would like to set a timeout on said receive calls, so there's no possibility of the read blocking indefinitely.

This appears to be a pretty common problem among Boost.Asio users, with the following past Stack Overflow questions on the topic:

- [C++ Boost ASIO: how to read/write with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553162/c-boost-asio-how-to-read-write-with-a-timeout)
- [asio::read with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126776/asioread-with-timeout)
- [boost asio timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041016/boost-asio-timeout)
- [How to set a timeout on blocking sockets in boost asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291871/how-to-set-a-timeout-on-blocking-sockets-in-boost-asio)

There may even be more. There are even [examples in the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/timeouts/blocking_udp_client.cpp) for how to implement synchronous operations with timeouts. They boil down to converting the synchronous operation to an asynchronous one, then starting it in parallel with a `asio::deadline_timer` . The timer's expiration handler can then cancel the asynchronous read in the event that the timeout expires. This looks something like this (snippet taken from the above linked example):

```
std::size_t receive(const boost::asio::mutable_buffer& buffer,
      boost::posix_time::time_duration timeout, boost::system::error_code& ec)
  {
    // Set a deadline for the asynchronous operation.
    deadline_.expires_from_now(timeout);

    // Set up the variables that receive the result of the asynchronous
    // operation. The error code is set to would_block to signal that the
    // operation is incomplete. Asio guarantees that its asynchronous
    // operations will never fail with would_block, so any other value in
    // ec indicates completion.
    ec = boost::asio::error::would_block;
    std::size_t length = 0;

    // Start the asynchronous operation itself. The handle_receive function
    // used as a callback will update the ec and length variables.
    socket_.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buffer),
        boost::bind(&client::handle_receive, _1, _2, &ec, &length));

    // Block until the asynchronous operation has completed.
    do io_service_.run_one(); while (ec == boost::asio::error::would_block);

    return length;
  }
```

This actually is a relatively clean solution: start the asynchronous operations, then manually poll the `asio::io_service` to execute asynchronous handlers one at a time until either the `async_receive()` completes or the timer expires.

*However, what about the case where the socket's underlying I/O service is already being run in one or more background threads?* In that case, there's no guarantee that the handlers for the asynchronous operations would be run by the foreground thread in the above snippet, so `run_one()` wouldn't return until some later, possibly unrelated, handler executes. This would make the socket reads rather unresponsive.

`asio::io_service` has a `poll_one()` function that will check the service's queue without blocking, but I don't see a good way to block the foreground thread (emulating the synchronous call behavior) until the handler executes, except for the case where there are no background threads that are executing `asio::io_service::run()` already.

I see two potential solutions, neither of which I like:

1. Use a condition variable or similar construct to make the foreground thread block after starting the asynchronous operations. In the handler for the `async_receive()` call, signal the condition variable to unblock the thread. This induces some locking for each read, which I would like to avoid, as I'd like to achieve the maximum possible throughput on the UDP socket reads. Otherwise, it is viable, and is probably what I would do unless a superior method presents itself.
2. Ensure that the socket has its own `asio::io_service` that is not being run by any background threads. This makes it harder to use asynchronous I/O with the socket in the cases where that is desired.

Any ideas for other ways to accomplish this in a safe way?

---

**Aside:** There are some answers to previous SO questions that advocate using the `SO_RCVTIMEO` socket option to implement the socket read timeout. This sounds great in theory, but it doesn't seem to work on my platform at least (Ubuntu 12.04, Boost v1.55). I can set the socket timeout, but it won't give the desired effect with Asio. The relevant code is in `/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp`:

```
size_t sync_recvfrom(socket_type s, state_type state, buf* bufs,
    size_t count, int flags, socket_addr_type* addr,
    std::size_t* addrlen, boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
  if (s == invalid_socket)
  {
    ec = boost::asio::error::bad_descriptor;
    return 0;
  }

  // Read some data.
  for (;;)
  {
    // Try to complete the operation without blocking.
    signed_size_type bytes = socket_ops::recvfrom(
        s, bufs, count, flags, addr, addrlen, ec);

    // Check if operation succeeded.
    if (bytes >= 0)
      return bytes;

    // Operation failed.
    if ((state & user_set_non_blocking)
        || (ec != boost::asio::error::would_block
          && ec != boost::asio::error::try_again))
      return 0;

    // Wait for socket to become ready.
    if (socket_ops::poll_read(s, 0, ec) < 0)
      return 0;
  }
}
```

If a socket read times out, the call to `recvfrom()` above would return `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`, which get translated to `boost::asio::error::try_again` or `boost::asio::error::would_block`. In this case, the above code will call the `poll_read()` function, which for my platform looks like:

```
int poll_read(socket_type s, state_type state, boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
  if (s == invalid_socket)
  {
    ec = boost::asio::error::bad_descriptor;
    return socket_error_retval;
  }

  pollfd fds;
  fds.fd = s;
  fds.events = POLLIN;
  fds.revents = 0;
  int timeout = (state & user_set_non_blocking) ? 0 : -1;
  clear_last_error();
  int result = error_wrapper(::poll(&fds, 1, timeout), ec);
  if (result == 0)
    ec = (state & user_set_non_blocking)
      ? boost::asio::error::would_block : boost::system::error_code();
  else if (result > 0)
    ec = boost::system::error_code();
  return result;
}
```

I snipped out the code conditionally compiled for other platforms. As you can see, if the socket is not a non-blocking socket, it ends up calling `poll()` with an infinite timeout, therefore blocking until the socket has data to be read (and foiling the attempt at a timeout). Thus, the `SO_RCVTIMEO` option is not effective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boost.Asio's support for [`futures`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/cpp2011/futures.html) may provide an elegant solution.  When an asynchronous operation is provided the [`boost::asio::use_future`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/use_future.html) value as its completion handler, the initiating function will return a `std::future` object that will receive the result of the operation.  Additionally, if the operation completes with failure, the `error_code` is converted into a `system_error` and passed to the caller via the `future`.

In the Boost.Asio C++11 Futures [datytime client example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/futures/daytime_client.cpp), a dedicated thread runs the `io_service`, and the main thread initiates asynchronous operations then synchronously waits on the completion of the operations, such as below:

```cpp
std::array<char, 128> recv_buf;
udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;
std::future<std::size_t> recv_length =
  socket.async_receive_from(
      boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf),
      sender_endpoint,
      boost::asio::use_future);

// Do other things here while the receive completes.

std::cout.write(
    recv_buf.data(),
    recv_length.get()); // Blocks until receive is complete.
```

When using `future`s, the overall approach to implementing a synchronous read with a timeout is the same as before.  Instead of using a synchronous read, one would use an asynchronous read and asynchronously wait on a timer.  The only minor change is that instead of instead of blocking on the `io_service` or periodically checking for the predicate, one would invoke `future::get()` to block until the operation has completed with success or failure (such as a timeout).

If C++11 is not available, then the return type for asynchronous operations can be customized for Boost.Thread's `future`, as demonstrated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22430940/1053968) answer.

Comment: Thanks for the insight; I wasn't aware that Asio could use futures in this way. Without looking at it, the implementation is probably similar to my existing approach of using a `condition_variable` to block the calling thread until the operation is complete, but it's nice to have something a bit more standard.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. This code fails for me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166923/).

Comment: Interesting approach I hadn't seen before. As a caveat, the io_context needs to be running in another thread, or the async_receive_from will never read data. You'd obviously want to `recv_length.wait_for(some_amount_of_time)`, and abort on failure, to achieve the timeout functionality.